# Need help to isolate snippet into function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a checkbox that when checked **shows** some content on my page.
If I uncheck it, the content is **hidden**.

I am trying to isolate the internal behaviour of that function into another function so I may reuse it:

```
    $('#some-id').change(function(){
        if ($(this).is(":checked")){
            show();
        } else {
            hide();
        }
    });
```

This is what I have tried:

```
    $('#some-id').change(function(){
        toggle();
    });

    function toggle() {
        $(this).is(":checked") ? show() : hide();
    }
```

But now it worked only for **hiding** the content when unchecking the field, but it does not **show** the content when the field is checked again anymore.

Is there any syntax error with that?

Comment: You need to pass the object in your `toggle()` as in `toggle(this)` and then `function toggle(obj) { $(obj).is(":checked") ? show() : hide(); }`

Comment: Thank you @CarstenLøvboAndersen it worked! Please consider posting this as an answer.

Comment: See [call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)  No need to pass `this` in as a parameter (not that that's a bad way to do it), change `toggle()` to `toggle.call(this)` then `this` inside toggle will be the same `this` inside `.change` (ie no code change to your toggle function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass a the checkbox object to the toggle function, otherwise the code wont know what to toggle.

```
let $checkBox = $('#somecheckbox'); //get the checkbox
$checkBox.change(function (){
  toggle($checkBox) //pass the checkbox to function
});

function toggle($checkBox) {
  $checkBox.is(":checked") ? show() : hide();
}
```

you could do that also with vanilla js and without jQuery pretty easily:

```
let checkbox = document.getElementById('someId');
checkbox.addEventlistener('change', () => {toggle(checkbox)});


function toggle(checkbox) {
   checkbox.checked ? hide() : show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `$(this)` to `$('#some-id')` in `function toggle()`

```js
$('#some-id').change(function() {
  toggle();
});

function toggle() {
  $('#some-id').is(":checked") ? show() : hide();
}
```

Comment: Fine until you want a second toggle, then you have to have 2 separate toggle functions instead of reusing one with a parameter.

Comment: @freedomn-m yes, it happens when he reuse it for another checkbox. But how about in case he wants to reuse it in another function only?

Comment: Indeed OPs "*so I may reuse it*" is entirely unclear.   Reuse the method to toggle #some-id or reuse the method to toggle #another-id.  (not my downvote, it's fine, just not what what people would define as "reusable")